# Displaying result of PHP function in a div

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, wordpress

So I am building a site in Wordpress and am allowing the user to register/login. However I would like to create a custom nav bar instead of the awful 'admin bar' and so I want to be able to load the user name into an html element. I know that the username can be retrieved with this php:
`<?php wp_get_current_user(); ?>`. But what I want to know is, what is the best way to pull that into a JS variable that can then be set to be the inner html of an element. Is there another more direct way to do this? I also looked at JSON but couldn't find much that relates to this kind of scenario.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use `echo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php):

```
<div>
    <?php echo wp_get_current_user(); ?>
</div>
```

You can add this to a JavaScript variable in the same way:

```
<script>
    var username = "<?php echo wp_get_current_user();?>";   
</script>
```

---

**EDIT** Looking at the [WP function reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user), the `wp_get_current_user()` is an object, and you can access its variables like so:

```
<?php
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . '<br />';
    echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . '<br />';
    echo 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . '<br />';
    echo 'User last name: ' . $current_user->user_lastname . '<br />';
    echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . '<br />';
    echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . '<br />';
?>
```

Therefore, you can use this script to output the *display name* into a `div` element:

```
<?php $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); ?>

<div>
    <?php echo $current_user->display_name; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I gave it a shot but doesn't seem to be working...I get no error but if I set that variable and then try and alert it, I just get the exact php code as the result.

Comment: Are you doing this in a `PHP` file or an `HTML` file?

Comment: it is a .php file. However I was testing the JS with the console when viewing the page.

Comment: You can't execute `PHP` code in the console. Try using `<?php var_dump(wp_get_current_user(); ?>` to see the content of the output of that function - could it be an array?

Comment: I believe it is an object: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user

Comment: I am going to try and test it now and will let you know if it is successful. Thanks